# Callback on 'save' on 'new node form' doesn't fire

Tags: 7, nodes, forms

**UPDATE:** 
Approach showed bellow has the same results -> doesn't work.

```
$new_form['#submit'][] = '_fmu_new_firm_under_user';
```

Separate button with only that callback doesn't work either. And what's weird, even if it has only the '_fmu_new_firm_under_user' callback it actually works the same way as 'save' button -> it saves the node and doesn't fire my callback.

```
$new_form['actions']['submit_and_create'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Vytvořit firmu'),
    '#submit' => array('_fmu_new_firm_under_user'),
  );
```

**Original message**

I've created a page with a 'myContentType_node_form' and attached a callback to the save button. The problem is that the callback is not fired when I press the button. To be more specific the default callback is fired - the node is saved - but my callback is not fired.

```
function _fmu_register_new_user_firm_callback($uid, $control_hash) { //a callback function for a menu item
      include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'node') . '/node.pages.inc' );
      $new_form = node_add('fm_firm');
      $new_form['uid']['#value'][] = $uid;

      $new_form['actions']['preview']['#access'] = false;
      $new_form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = '_fmu_new_firm_under_user';

      dsm($new_form);
      return $new_form;
  }

function _fmu_new_firm_under_user($form, &$form_state) {

  $user = user_load($form['uid']['#value']);
  $user->fmu_users_firm[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['target_id'] = $form->nid;
  user_save($user);

  dsm($user);
}
```

DSM of the form before returning it:

```
actions (Array, 16 elements)

    #type (String, 7 characters ) actions
    submit (Array, 23 elements)
        #type (String, 6 characters ) submit
        #access (Boolean) TRUE
        #value (String, 4 characters ) Save
        #weight (Integer) 5
        #submit (Array, 2 elements)
            0 (String, 16 characters ) node_form_submit | (Callback) node_form_submit();
            1 (String, 24 characters ) _fmu_new_firm_under_user | (Callback) _fmu_new_firm_under_user();
        #input (Boolean) TRUE
        #name (String, 2 characters ) op
        #button_type (String, 6 characters ) submit
        #executes_submit_callback (Boolean) TRUE
        #limit_validation_errors (Boolean) FALSE
        #process (Array, 1 element)
        #theme_wrappers (Array, 1 element)
        #defaults_loaded (Boolean) TRUE
        #tree (Boolean) FALSE
        #parents (Array, 1 element)
        #array_parents (Array, 2 elements)
        #processed (Boolean) TRUE
        #required (Boolean) FALSE
        #attributes (Array, 0 elements)
        #title_display (String, 6 characters ) before
        #id (String, 11 characters ) edit-submit
        #ajax_processed (Boolean) FALSE
        #sorted (Boolean) TRUE
    preview (Array, 23 elements)
    #theme_wrappers (Array, 1 element)
    #process (Array, 2 elements)
    #weight (Integer) 100
    #defaults_loaded (Boolean) TRUE
    #tree (Boolean) FALSE
    #parents (Array, 1 element)
    #array_parents (Array, 1 element)
    #processed (Boolean) TRUE
    #required (Boolean) FALSE
    #attributes (Array, 1 element)
    #title_display (String, 6 characters ) before
    #id (String, 12 characters ) edit-actions
    submit_and_create (Array, 3 elements)
        #type (String, 6 characters ) submit
        #value (String, 15 characters ) Vytvořit firmu
        #submit (Array, 1 element)
            0 (String, 24 characters ) _fmu_new_firm_under_user | (Callback) _fmu_new_firm_under_user();
```

Comment: // are you sure its not fired?
function _fmu_new_firm_under_user($form, &$form_state) {
  dpm("hello world");
}

Comment: Yes, I'm sure it is not fired. Neither dpm nor dsm renders any text.

Comment: `node_add()` already calls `drupal_get_form()`, and presumably your function is also being wrapped by `drupal_get_form()`? By the time you get the form back from `node_add()` it's already been processed so I think `hook_form_alter()` would be the only way to effect it with your current method. The `hook_node_submit()` method would be preferable IMO

Comment: No it's not, this is callback function for a URL (menu item). 

BTW: Check update.

Comment: Might be that the form is already cached as `drupal_get_form()` has already run, so when the page reloads and the original form is retrieved it doesn't have your changes. You'll be able to affect things on the initial display as that will use the live array you're manipulating, not the cache. Just a theory. The standard way to alter a form is `hook_form_alter()`, I've never had any joy with the method you're trying (haven't tried it in a while though)

Comment: But if I add a new button appears there so my changes are processed. Just the callbacks don't work...

Comment: Clive: As it seems you're right. The form is pre-processed at least the callbacks are which is the reason why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be better off using [hook_node_submit](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_submit/7) which would fire when any node is submitted.

You can make it specific to your node by the following:

```
function MODULE_node_submit($node, $form, &$form_state)
{
    if ($node->type == "NODE-TYPE")
    {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it a bit overkill for one callback attached to one form?

I mean, my approach should work, shouln't it?

Comment: I don't think, it's one function call and an if statement if the node is not the one you want. Plus, it  will reduce your code and increase maintainability

Comment: Ok, I'll think about it. Anyway, I would like to know why my approach doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You don't add the callback to the actions, you add it directly to the `['#submit']`

Soo

```
$new_form['#submit'][] = '_fmu_new_firm_under_user';
```

If you are trying to add it to a button you would do something like

```
$new_form['buttons']['continue']['#submit'][]
```

Comment: The first suggested approach doesn't work (tried it), the second one is the same as mine (actions is the name of the group in which the buttons are so I'm adding it directly to a button).

Comment: Add a `die();` after the `dsm();` and refresh the cache. What you posted should work.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. The callback is just simply not fired, damn.